# Spark Architecture for processing small binary files saved in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, hdfs, apache-kafka

I don't know how to build architecture for following use case:

I have an Web application where users can upload files(pdf&pptx) and directories to be processed. After upload is complete web application put this files and directories in HDFS, then send a messages on kafka with path to this files.

Spark Application read messages from kafka streaming, collect them on master(driver), and after that process them. I collect messages first because i need to move the code to data, and not move data where the message is received. I understood that spark assign job to executor which already have file locally.

I have issues with kafka because i was forced to collect them first for the above reason, and when want to create checkpoint app crash "because you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable" even if the code run before adding checkpointing( I use sparkContext there because i need to save data to ElasticSearch and PostgreSQL. I don't know how exactly i can do code upgrading in this conditions.

I read about hadoop small files problems, and I understand what problems are in this case. I read that HBase is a better solution to save small files than just save in hdfs. Other problem in hadoop small files problems is big number of mappers and reducers created for computation, but i don't understand if this problem there in spark.

What is the best architecture for this use case?
How to do Job Scheduling? It's kafka good for that? or I need to use other service like rabbitMQ or something else?
Exist some method to add jobs to an running Spark application through some REST API? 
How is the best way to save files? Is better to use Hbase because i have small files(<100MB)? Or I need to use SequenceFile? I think SequenceFile isn't for my use case because i need to reprocess some files randomly.

What is the best architecture do you think for this use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no one single "the best" way to build architecture. You need to make decisions and stick to them. Make the architecture flexible and decoupled so that you can easily replace components if needed.

Consider following stages/layers in your architecture:

1. Retrieval/Acquisition/Transport of source data (files)
2. Data processing/transformation
3. Data archival

As a retrieval component, I would use Flume. It is flexible, supports a lot of sources, channels (including Kafka) and sinks. In your case you can configure source that monitors the directory and extracts the newly received files.

For data processing/transformation - it depends what task you are solving. You probably decided on Spark Streaming. Spark streaming can be integrated with Flume sink (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html) There are other options available, e.g. Apache Storm. Flume combines very well with Storm. Some transformations can also be applied in Flume.

For data archival - do not store/archive the files directly in Hadoop, unless they are bigger than few hundredths of megabytes. One solution would be to put them in HBase.

Make your architecture more flexible. I would place processed files in a temporary HDFS location and have some job regualarly archive them into zip, HBase, Hadoop Archive (there is such an animal) or any other solution.

Consider using Apache NiFi (aka HDF - Hortonworks Data Flow). It uses internally queues, provides a lot of processors. It can make your life easier and get the workflow developed in minutes. Give it a try. There is nice [Hortonworks tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-ropes-apache-nifi/) which , combined with HDP Sandbox running on a virtual machine/Docker, can bring you up to speed in very short time (1-2 hours?).

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! I have some question:

I could use Flume for data ingestion, it's a good idea, but how can I reprocess on demand some files already added to HDFS?

I think my architecture is bad, because it's kind of ETL on batch files, and it's not based on streaming, but i need to run some algorithms on batch files on demand, and i don't know how to add jobs in spark without queue(which it's a bad idea).

How can add jobs to spark?

Thanks